# Two plots "with boxes" next to each other with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to have two data series plotted in one graph as boxes in gnuplot. The script looks like this currently:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color
set title "Distribution of the extrepreneur PnL. Loan $6."
set output 'pnl_loan6.eps'


#set xrange [0:]
set xlabel "Discounted profit"

set style fill solid 0.8 border -1
plot 'pnl_loan6.txt' using 1:2 title 'PnL high risk (xi=1)' with boxes,\
     'pnl_loan6.txt' using 1:3 title 'PnL high risk (xi=1.5)' with boxes
```

however the two series overlap. Instead of the overlap I would like to have one series draw its box in the left half of the existing box, and the other one in the right half, so that they effectively alternate. How can I do it?

EDIT:

1. I tried a histogram plot, but this didn't look very good. The xtics were not what I was after and there were spaces in between the columns.
2. Sample data (first 20 columns out of 100):

Data:

```
-10.000000 20251.000000 31825.000000
-4.892638 26743.000000 21310.000000
0.214725 20362.000000 14590.000000
5.322087 13023.000000 9645.000000
10.429449 7730.000000 6347.000000
15.536812 4636.000000 4331.000000
20.644174 2714.000000 2964.000000
25.751536 1647.000000 2121.000000
30.858899 1044.000000 1586.000000
35.966261 648.000000 1106.000000
41.073624 396.000000 873.000000
46.180986 257.000000 685.000000
51.288348 166.000000 471.000000
56.395711 101.000000 369.000000
61.503073 83.000000 321.000000
66.610435 52.000000 260.000000
71.717798 40.000000 184.000000
76.825160 30.000000 172.000000
81.932522 21.000000 143.000000
87.039885 11.000000 116.000000
```

Comment: What kind of data are you plotting?  (are the contents in the first field of your datafile sequential integers?  If I had a small datafile to work with, I might be able to give you a more complete and tested answer )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are after but maybe this little hackerish approach will do the trick:

```
set style fill solid 0.8 border -1
set boxwidth 0.5 relative
plot 'pnl_loan6.txt' using ($1+1.27684075):2 title 'PnL high risk (xi=1)' with boxes,\
     'pnl_loan6.txt' using ($1-1.27684075):3 title 'PnL high risk (xi=1.5)' with boxes
```

The difference to your script is

1. setting the boxwidth do 0.5 relative
2. offsetting the plots by half the distance on the x-axis (this only works because your x-axis scaling is equidistant.

Anyhow this is the resulting plot:

[image]

PS:
You might want to think about a logarithmic scaling on the y-axis with `set logscale y` which would result in this plot:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I am after! Where are the constants `+-1.27684075` coming from? Are they likely to change if the data changes?

Comment: The constants are coming from your data.  Your data is spaced with a delta x=5.1 -- So each box's width is half that distance (~2.55).  The above script moves the first boxes half a boxwidth to the left (-1.27) and the second boxes half a boxwidth to the right (1.27).  So, the constants will change value if the spacing of the x-data changes.

Comment: One could use the `stats` command (I love it) to extract this information automatically: `stats 'file.txt' using 1 every ::::1 nooutput; ofs=0.25*(STATS_max - STATS_min); plot ... using ($1-ofs)...`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `histogram` style ... or maybe `set boxwidth`.

**EDIT**

For `boxwidth` see Woltan's answer -- After seeing your datafile, this is probably the best approach.

You could do:

```
set style histogram cluster gap 0
plot "datafile.dat" u 2:xtic(1) with histogram ...
```

However, you'd have a much overcrowded x-axis in this case -- But in the case where you want to label the axis with strings, this method works great.

One final note:
It is probably a good idea to do something like the following --

```
set style fill solid 0.8 border -1
set boxwidth 0.5 relative
plot 'datafile.dat' using ($1+1.27684075):2 title 'PnL high risk (xi=1)' with boxes,\
     '' using ($1-1.27684075):3 title 'PnL high risk (xi=1.5)' with boxes lc rgb "#0000ff"
```

This changes the color of the green boxes to blue (#0000ff) since ~5% of people are red/green colorblind.  (You could probably use "blue" instead of "#0000ff" -- but the latter is more general).

Comment: Hi, I tried the histogram style but it seems to do a different thing. Could you give an example of this set boxwidth? How do I specify I want half of the original? Plus I need to move one to the left and the other one to the right?

Answer (score 0):

This links also has a simple nice solution of using "with boxes" instead of histograms for both when there is only one group of data, and when there are more. It worked very well for me, and does not have all those difficult to understand offset calculation suggested in the accepted answer:

http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.ca/2011/09/plot-histograms-using-boxes.html

Comment: The solution in the blog post is pretty much identical to the accepted solution.