# How to add offset to time-based data when plotting in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to add an offset to the time-based data from a file which I want to plot using gnuplot. I can plot the data just fine, but when I try to add a time-based offset the graph is empty.

The purpose is to plot multiple bars next to each other, like described here, but with time-based data: [Two plots "with boxes" next to each other with gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826757/two-plots-with-boxes-next-to-each-other-with-gnuplot)

Data file:

```
00:00 7719
01:00 20957
02:00 15989
03:00 9711
04:00 1782
05:00 871
06:00 4820
07:00 860
08:00 873
09:00 848
10:00 879
11:00 726
12:00 944
13:00 924
14:00 996
15:00 806
16:00 848
17:00 967
18:00 2277
19:00 2668
20:00 32183
21:00 14414
22:00 20426
23:00 16140
```

I am trying to plot the data using this code:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%S"
set format x "%H"
set style fill solid 0.6 border -1
set boxwidth 0.3 relative
plot ["00:00":"23:30"] 'data.dat' using ($1-0.3):2 with boxes, \
  'data.dat' using ($1+0.3):2 with boxes
```

This is only a test - the real data file has additional data columns, and I am trying to place the boxes next to each other using offset, however I'm having no luck with time-based data and offsets.

Without offset the code is fine:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%S"
set format x "%H"
set style fill solid 0.6 border -1
set boxwidth 0.3 relative
plot ["00:00":"23:30"] 'data.dat' using 1:2 with boxes
```

Answer (score 18):

For computations with timedata you must use the `timecolumn()` function, which parses a time string from a column according to the `set timefmt` settings. The result is a time stamp in seconds. So, for the offset you must use the according time in seconds:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%S"
set format x "%H"
set style fill solid 0.6 border -1
set boxwidth 0.3 relative
set xrange["00:00":"23:30"]
set style data boxes
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2, \
     '' using (timecolumn(1)+60*20):($2*0.5), \
     '' using (timecolumn(1)+60*40):($2*0.7)
```

This gives:

[image]

As another variant you can use the `histogram` style, and format the xtic labels using `strftime` and `timecolumn`:

```
set timefmt "%H:%S"
set style fill solid 0.6 border -1
set style data histogram
set style histogram clustered gap 1
plot 'data.dat' using 2:xtic(strftime('%H', timecolumn(1))), \
     '' using ($2*0.5), \
     '' using ($2*0.7)
```

That gives:

[image]

You get no separation between two data blocks with `set style histogram clustered gap 0`.

In order to control the tic labelling, you may use something like

```
plot 'data.dat' using 2:xtic((int($0) % 2 == 0) ? strftime('%H', timecolumn(1)) : '')
```

which prints only the label of every second entry in the data file (`$0` refers to the row number).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for. I'm sorry I don't have the rep to vote your answer up :-(

Comment: @user2846740 You can accept this answer to credit his/her work.