# bash: What the sequence below tries to do?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use a couple of bash scripts that are supposed to plot some data using a tool named iperf3. I found the mentioned scripts in a GIT repository several years old. I have this sequence:

```
...
echo \$data \<\<EOD
for j in *.json
do
  dt=$(basename "$j" .json)
  if jq -e '.error' < $j
  then
    echo $(readlink -f $j) has an error, skipping >&2
    cat $j >&2
    continue
  fi
  sent=$(jq '.end.sum_sent.bits_per_second / 8' < "$j")
  received=$(jq '.end.sum_received.bits_per_second / 8' < "$j")
  echo "$dt" "$sent" "$received"
done
echo EOD
....
```

My uderstanding is that here the code tries to create a heredoc file containing the for ... done loop and to store in the variable named "data" the result of its execution. However, this doesn't work and bash flags the following error:

```
$data <<EOD
^
line 0: invalid command
```

So, I have several questions:

1. Is that syntax supposed to work and, if yes, why it doesn't in my case ?
2. Admitting that the syntax above is not supposed to work and that the script I found is somehow broken, how could I rewrite it such that to store in the variable data the result of the execution of the given hereisdoc ?

Many thanks in advance,

Nicolas DUMINIL

I'm updating the post with the entire code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Grateful for the answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447348
shopt -s nullglob

echo \$data \<\<EOD
for j in *.json
do
  dt=$(basename "$j" .json)
  if jq -e '.error' < $j
  then
    echo $(readlink -f $j) has an error, skipping >&2
    cat $j >&2
    continue
  fi
  sent=$(jq '.end.sum_sent.bits_per_second / 8' < "$j")
  received=$(jq '.end.sum_received.bits_per_second / 8' < "$j")
  echo "$dt" "$sent" "$received"
done
echo EOD

cat << END
set term svg size 800,600 fname "Helvetica Neue" fsize 9 rounded dashed
set title "Generated by https://github.com/kaihendry/iperf3chart"
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.9
set xtic rotate by -45 scale 0 font ",8"
set key top left
# Convert bytes to megabytes
set format y '%.0s %cB'
plot \$data using 2:xticlabels(strftime("%H:%M %Y-%m-%d",column(1))) t 'up', '' u 3 t 'down'
END
```

Comment: The `...` part looks very important. Ex. if you would have `data=cat` then `$data <<EOD` would work. Probably `$data` was supposed to expand to something. Like `data=send_data_from_stdout_to_remove_server; $data <<EOD`

Comment: @Nicolas : In short: The script tries to create another program, which indeed looks like something creating a HERE document. But aside of the correct remark given by KamilCuk, the error message you get does not look as if the script created dynamically in that way, has been run by `bash`, because if it were, the error message would look have a prefix before saying _line 0:_, and the prefix would be either _bash_ or the name of the script being executed.

Comment: I updated the post to add the full code, perhaps it clarifies

Comment: when **updating** the code, you should *change* the existing code, rather than adding another copy.

Comment: @umläute: this comment is really very usefull and will be capital in helping me solve my issue, thank you so much.

Comment: it might indeed be capital for people who want to help *you* to solve *your* problem in their *spare time* for *free* to not have to wade through a number of versions of the same transcript until the find one that has all the information needed. thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @umlaute: It might but it doesn't. And you don't seem to belong to this group of people wanting to help the others. What exactly gives you this pretention to think that it's your role ro tell the others what to do, how to edit their own posts, what to copy, where, etc ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question. The code excerpt above works as expected as soon as executed with bash 4.
Kind regards,
Nicolas